# What is the best practice concerning overload

Tags: c#

I wonder what is the best practice or at least what is more standar about overload. I'm using c# 3.5 so I don't have optional parameter. Let say I have the following method :

```
Foo(string param1, string param2)
{
    SqlConnection connection = SM.Program.GetConnection();
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table" +
                          "SET Pla = @pla " +
                          "WHERE Foo = @foo";

    try
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pla", param1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foo", param2);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And that I need an overload with another parameter, let say an sqltransaction

```
Foo(string param1, string param2, SqlTransaction trans)
```

The second method would basically be the same but it would do the operation in a transaction

Now I'm wondering what should I do? Only 1 method that accep a null argurment as the transaction and in that case don't use any or 2 methods but pretty mutch copy/paste the code in except for the transaction?

What is considered the best practice for that kind of thing?

EDIT : I think the general idea seem to do the chaining between overload. But I still wonder in that case isn't accepting null argument in a method is a kind of bad thing?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  "best practices" are very subjective; it all depends on the context of your question (hint: we need to see more than just method signatures).  Not to mention any good answer really needs to see your code so it can be refactored. Context matters, and any good answer to this question will need more context than you have provided. Can you help us out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Going by the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you should never copy-paste code.

Therefore, having two methods like this, you should always have some kind of chaining.

```
public void Foo(string param1, param2) {
       Foo(param1, param2, null);
}

public void Foo(string param1, string param2, SqlTransaction trans) {
      //do stuff, handle null value for trans
}
```

**Update regarding default parameters**

Supplying a default parameter with a single method instead of overloading could be considered bad practice in some situations, especially when writing libraries:

```
//assembly1.dll
public void Foo(int a, int b, int c = 3) { ... }

//assembly2.dll
void Bar() {
     Foo(1,2);
}
```

What happens is that the compiler replaces the call `Foo(1,2)` with `Foo(1,2,3)`.

Now, let's say we want to change the default for `c` to 4 and update assembly1.dll without changing assembly2.dll.

We would expect to call `Foo(1,2,4)` but in reality, `Foo(1,2,3)` is still invoked, because the default value is stored in the caller's location!

By using overloads, the default value `3` is stored in assembly1.dll, where it belongs.

Comment: DRY only addresses the best way to implement the overloading approach. It says very little about whether overloading is better or worse than default parameters. (Actually, it slightly favours default parameters.)

Comment: Regarding default parameters, they have their own set of pros/cons compared to traditional overloads. IMO, using default parameters vs overloads should be based on those quirks.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Updated my answer, with arguments against using default parameters.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans original answer was better since I'm using c# 3.5 I can't have default parameter

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer because this answer explains what my answer said much more throughly.

Answer (score 1):

I think overloading is clearer than passing `null` for some arguments. I would implement it like this:

```
Foo(string param1, string param2)
{
    Foo("param", "param", null);
}

Foo(string param1, string param2, SqlTransaction trans)
{
    //Do stuff...
}
```

This way you do not have to copy and paste code.

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose that your function take x arguments. With just one function then you 'll need `x` `if else` to check what to do if the specific argument value is null or not.

Method overloading is more much cleaner and readable.